# Workbooks.Open failing in specific circumstances

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a a function in my project that's is built to look for a workbook, check if it's open, then open that workbook if it's closed.

```
    Public Function CheckOpen(wbName As String)
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim Ret_type As Integer
    Dim strMsg As String
    Dim strTitle As String
    Dim tempstr As String
    Dim x As Integer, y As Integer

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks(wbName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    strTitle = "Workbook Not Open"
    strMsg = "Workbook " + wbName + " isn't open, press 'Retry' to fix."

    If wb Is Nothing Then
        'The workbook isn't open
         Ret_type = MsgBox(strMsg, vbRetryCancel + vbQuestion, strTitle)

         Select Case Ret_type
            Case 4
             'Retry Case
               On Error Resume Next
               For x = 1 To 2
                    For y = 1 To 2
                        Workbooks.Open (FindFilePath(x) + FileEndingManager(wbName, y))
                        Debug.Print (FindFilePath(x) + FileEndingManager(wbName, y))
                    Next y
               Next x
            Case 2
             'Cancel Case
                MsgBox "You clicked 'CANCEL' button."
            End Select
      End If

    End Sub
```

TO CLARIFY: This function works when called directly. As in:

```
    Sub TestCheck()
         Call CheckOpen("WorkbookName")
    End Sub
```

That's fine. Everything works. However, when I Call this function from a function entered in the actual spreadsheet the MsgBox appears, but it never opens the required workbook.

I don't understand what is going on.

Comment: Is it possible that the workbook name within the function is misspelled? Since we know the one in your test routine is spelled correctly, I would try to copy that name and paste it to the one within the function that's not working.

Comment: A function called from a cell cannot do things like opening workbooks.

Comment: As @jkpieterse points out, functions entered into cells should only effect that cell, so things like opening workbooks is prohibited. Would you really want this function to run each time Excel calculates? You might consider including a button on the sheet that runs your `TestCheck`, perhaps picking up the workbook name from the selected cell for instance, as a better method..?

Comment: Ok, yeah, this is what I was afraid of. I'll include an error message instructing the user to that they need to keep certain workbooks open. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

### Using Functions (UDFs)

As mentioned in comments @jkpieterse

> A function called from a cell cannot do things like opening workbooks

**Functions** are able to be called from a cell just like Excel's built in functions and they **always return something to the cell** (even if it's only an error).

For a function to return something, other than an error, it must have a line like

`FunctionName = *a value that complies with the function declaration*`

Functions are available in auto-complete in Excel, even if they return a `#VALUE!` error which will occur if you don't set a return as described above.  That's probably going to frustrate users!

Any other errors in a UDF will also cause a `#VALUE!` error and the only way to find them is by stepping through the function using F8.  They don't show up at compile time!

So there are at least 2 reasons not to use a function where a sub would suffice.

If you want to change any book or sheet objects then **declare a Sub** procedure.

**Use UDFs sparingly!**

### To answer your question:

I've tried to refactor your code into a worksheet callable function that will work with a Sub procedure while still using your variables.

I don't know what `FindFilePath(x)` or `FileEndingManager(wbName, Y)` do so assume they do work.

```
Public Function CheckOpen(wbName As String) As Boolean
Dim wb As Workbook

On Error Resume Next
Set wb = Application.Workbooks(wbName)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not wb Is Nothing Then
    CheckOpen = True 'the essence of a "Function" - it returns a value!
End If

End Function
```

Or you could use this alternate function that doesn't require `On Error Resume Next`

```
Public Function CheckOpen1(wbName As String) As Boolean
Dim wb As Workbook

For Each wb In Workbooks 'in all the workbooks you have open
    If wb.Name = wbName Then
        CheckOpen = True 'if not, CheckOpen will remain FALSE
    End If
Next

End Function
```

Then your Sub procedure looks like:

```
FileEndingManager(wbName, y)
Sub TestCheck()
Dim Ret_type As Integer
Dim strMsg As String
Dim strTitle As String
Dim tempstr As String
Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
     
If Not CheckOpen("WorkbookName") Then
    strTitle = "Workbook Not Open"
    strMsg = "WorkbookName isn't open, press 'Retry' to fix."
    Ret_type = MsgBox(strMsg, vbRetryCancel + vbQuestion, strTitle)
    
    Select Case Ret_type
    Case 4
        'Retry Case
        On Error Resume Next
        For x = 1 To 2
            For y = 1 To 2
                Workbooks.Open (FindFilePath(x) + FileEndingManager(wbName, y))
                Debug.Print (FindFilePath(x) + FileEndingManager(wbName, y))
            Next y
        Next x
        On Error GoTo 0 'end the Resume Next ASAP
        'Check if the x, y loop has opened WorkbookName
        If Not CheckOpen("WorkbookName") Then 'probably can't be opened
            strMsg = "WorkbookName can't be opened! Clicking OK will exit sub."
            MsgBox strMsg, vbCritical, strTitle
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Case 2 'Tell user something they know! Not necessary
        'Cancel Case
        MsgBox "You clicked 'CANCEL' button." 'delete this line and just exit
        Exit Sub
    End Select
End If
'Haven't exited yet so safe to proceed
'...do things with WorkbookName
End Sub
```